# users and nohup

Tags: server, users, nohup

How can I tell if there are processes running on a system owned by non-system users?

I thought the [users](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/users.1.html) utility command did the trick, but it only seems to track login sessions and not processes launched via [nohup](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/nohup.1posix.html). Is there a way to find even these processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prints the PIDs of all processes owned by a user with UID > 999:

```
ps -A -o uid,pid | awk '{if($1>999)print $2}'
```

Note that this includes things like cronjobs which may or may not what you want.

If you want to see the users instead of the PIDs:

```
 ps -A --no-headers -o uid,user | awk '{if($1>999)print $2}'| sort | uniq
```

Comment: Thanks for the script. I was looking for something with similar output to 'users'. The main purpose of it were to find out who are using the given machines of the cluster, so I can notify them through e-mail.

Comment: @Meteorhead: Added a command that lists the users

Comment: Wow, just wow. Infinitely simpler than the bash monstrosity which I had.